# "technical Support of" vs "technical support for"

Tags: word-choice

We created a software, but we run a business that provides technical support. In other words, we receive fees for providing technical support. We need to specifically imply that the support is limited to only the software that we created. How do we say it in a sentence? Do we say

> We are in the business of providing technical support for Software X.

OR

> We are in the business of providing technical support of Software X.

Is there any difference between the two forms?

I suspect the first form is the correct form, but I have received draft documents from the legal team that use the second form. I am in correspondence with them on this, but they are slow to respond, sometimes taking months just for such a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For" is correct. "Of" makes less sense, because it would mean the support belonged to or was part of the software. "Of" can mean other things, but nothing else that wold make sense in this context. You could say something like, "In support of the software," but here, "for" makes a lot more sense.